# Reverting the last action on git?

Tags: git, github

I am just new to git and I pushed a file to the repository but it just overwrites and deleted every work on our groups' repository, how do I undo this. as fast as possible without anyone noticing.

When I try git revert  it gives bad object.

step by step I used

```
clone <repsurl>
```

in the git bash
than I add somefile to local directory and used the command

```
git add <somfile>

git commit -m "somecomment"
```

and finnaly

```
git push
```

I think my mistake was not using

```
git add .
```

any way at the end Only my files were in the rep.

Comment: Revert is a local operation, but the unwanted push has modified the distant repo, not yours. Broadly speaking, the solution would involve pushing the old ref (the one you overwrote) in place of the (bad) new one. I'll also advise to tell the others, secret can make things worse. Doing a bad move is bad, but lying will be considered far worse by many people.

Comment: i still have the old rep in my local computer how do i push it

Comment: You'd have to `git push --force <oldRef>:<Destinationbranch>` but then again, you might do more damage by trying to conceal the fact.... I'll stop arguing about it but beware ^^

Comment: what should i put in <oldRef>:<Destinationbranch>

Comment: the `<oldRef>` would be the SHA-1 hash of the commit previously at the tip of `<destinationBranch>`. You might find it more easily by inspecting either the distant repo or your local, but it's difficult to say without knowing ANYthing about your repo...

Comment: it says could not resolve host name

Comment: How did you push? If you did not use --force, you did not overwrite anything, you just added a new version of the file. You can go back to the previous version by checking out the corresponding commit.

Comment: In your question, you should clarify which commands you used and what you did exactly.

Comment: Stop what you're doing. Speak to your team and admit you did something wrong before you destroy the repo it even further.  Everyone makes mistakes, but to conceal it often does much more damage than owning it.

Comment: https://ohshitgit.com/

Comment: @MFnx thats exactly the case i did not force push, I first created an empty folder in my computer than i clone the whole rep with clone to my computer then i add some files lets call it <somefile> to that file in my local pc finally i used push <somefile> and when i cheked the rep online only my files were there. how ever as you said previous version is there if i click show the repo before that commit etc. so exatcly how do i chekc out my commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `git push`, you don't overwrite files, you just add a version of the files. A picture of that version is a `commit` which is identified by a `commit hash`.

I highly recommend you read https://git-scm.com/docs. It's short, and it will answer a lot of questions for you.

So, to answer your question: *how can I undo this?* The question should be: how can I get the previous files back? As always, in `git`, there are many ways to achieve something. I won't post a `git` tutorial here, but I'll try to provide you with some basic commands which would allow you to do what you need. However, if you do not understand them fully, I insist, you should read the docs.

I will assume your working area is clean, that is, everything has been committed and pushed to your remote. Local and remote repositories are fully synced.

When executing `git log`, you can see all the commits you have done on your branch (and parent branches). Some useful variant: `git push -10 --oneline`. This shows the last 10 commits in a short version (one line per commit). For each commit, you will see the commit hash (the identifier of your commit). To check out to that commit, you can do:

```
git checkout <commit_hash>
```

After that, the version of your files are those corresponding to that commit. But, note that you are not on a branch anymore. If you want to stay on your branch, but reset your files to the version of a given commit, you can do:

```
git reset --hard <commit_hash>
```

Sometimes, it is useful to do a soft reset:

```
git reset --soft <commit_hash>
```

This resets your last commit to the one identified by `<commit_hash>`, but does not change the version of your files. Instead, those changes are in the staged area.

There are also some useful variants like:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

This last command does a soft reset to your previous commit (the commit before the one `HEAD` is pointing to).

Comment: thanks when i try checkout it say bad tree also when i git log it gives an old log for another rep i have

Comment: It seems your local repo is messed up. Try to delete the local repo, and clone it again from the remote.

Comment: okay now git log works when i say git chekout hash it said head is now at hash

Comment: so if I use git reset --soft HEAD~1 does it undo my last commit?

Comment: Those are not compatible. Check out to your branch (master I guess). Then do git reset --soft HEAD~1
This resets your last commit to the previous one. But it keeps the version of last commit in the staging area (ready for commit). 
If you don't care about your last version, you do: git reset --hard HEAD~1

Comment: okay i did git reset --hard <hash of the last good commit > it changed the local files as find now should i just use git push ?

Comment: i used git push but it said could not pushtip of your current branch is behind

Comment: then do git pull and then git push.
Just do: git checkout master, git pull, git reset --hard HEAD~1, and finally: git push -f origin master

Comment: note that with this, you loose your last version (the version you and your coworkers don't want)